# How to insert a double space into a bibliography section?

Tags: bibliographies, line-spacing, apa6, apacite

I am writing a thesis using `apacite` and I do need to insert a double spacing into my bibliography section, but I can't manage to do it since my document contains a `\onehalfspacing` in its preamble. How could I change that?

This is my mwe:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,%
               twoside=semi,%
               headings=small,%
               chapterprefix=true,%
               listof=flat]%
{scrbook}
%\onehalfspacing
\usepackage[numberedbib,nosectionbib]{apacite}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage [french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\bibnewpage 
{\raggedright 
\nocite{}
\bibliographystyle{apacite} 
\bibliography{mabiblio}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could use `\doublespacing` in  a group around the bibliography.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your given code has some problems.  In the following MWE I corrected them.

- To get rid of the error message just move command `\onehalfspacing` from the preamble to the document.
- You missed calling `setspace` in the preamble.
- I added `\doublespacing` to the group building the bibliography (see comments)
- I added a bib file with package `filecontents`

With the following MWE

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Goossens,
  author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and 
               Samarin, Alexander},
  title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
  edition   = {1},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location  = {Reading, Mass.},
  year      = {1994},
}
@Book{adams,
  title     = {The Restaurant at the End of the Universe},
  author    = {Douglas Adams},
  series    = {The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  publisher = {Pan Macmillan},
  year      = {1980},
}
@article{feynman,
  title     = {Very High-Energy Collisions of Hadrons},
  author    = {Richard P. Feynman},
  journal   = {Phys. Rev. Lett.},
  volume    = {23},
  issue     = {24},
  pages     = {1415--1417},
  year      = {1969},
  month     = {Dec},
  doi       = {10.1103/PhysRevLett.23.1415},
  url       = {http://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevLett.23.1415},
  publisher = {American Physical Society},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[%
  fontsize=12pt,%
  twoside=semi,%
  headings=small,%
  chapterprefix=true,%
  listof=flat
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[numberedbib,nosectionbib]{apacite} 

\usepackage{setspace} % <===============================================
\usepackage{blindtext}


\begin{document}
\onehalfspacing % <=====================================================
\blindtext

\bibnewpage 
{%start grouping
  \doublespacing % <====================================================
  \raggedright 
  \nocite{*}
  \bibliographystyle{apacite} 
  \bibliography{\jobname}
}%end grouping

\end{document}
```

you get the following pages. First the normal text:

[image]

second the bibliography:

[image: bibliography]

Comment: It works very well! Thanks for your suggestions!